# Reset code and userform window positions in Microsoft Office VBA IDE

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, vba, window

When we open UserForms and code modules in a Microsoft Office VBA project (Word, Excel or Access), we can change the size and location of these windows. MS Office saves the last position for these windows and then restore it when we open them again. Is there a way to reset the positions of these windows to default?

If you worked with VB6, this operation is equivalent to deleting the .vbw file for a VB6 project file (.vbp). In VS.NET this can be done by deleting files like .suo and .vbproj.user and the like.

Answer (score -1):

I think the following link will be helpful trying to figure a solution for yourself.

[Userform startup position - MrExcel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/671108-userform-startup-position.html)

A couple of suggestions that are given there:

- Base the position of the userform on named ranges in your Excel workbook
- Place the UserForm window in a specific position in relation to your Excel-program every time it loads or activates.

Comment: I asked about the position of the windows solely in the VBA IDE when we are doing our development work, not when we run them (F5).

Comment: Ah OK, I missed that clue in your question.  Using the term "VBA IDE" or "VBE" would've made it a bit more clearer.  On the topic of the exact position for any module/class-windows in VBE I do not know a solution to that.